# Godzilla eating other monsters?

Tags: godzilla, kaiju

I was watching one of my favorite Godzilla movies ([*Godzilla: Tokyo S.O.S.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla:_Tokyo_S.O.S.)) and looking at the remains of Kamoebas, a thought occurred.

Has there been any instance of a kaiju eating another?

Godzilla has only ever killed, I can't remember a time when he has consumed an enemy.

I am excluding Godzilla's fight with Orga because Orga didn't succeed in his consumption.

Comment: I'm fairly sure Godzilla is a vegetarian; http://i.imgur.com/eYXMSFA.gif

Comment: A vegetarian diet doesn't seem likely because he has teeth and jaws are designed to do damage to beings similar to him, as seen in "Godzilla Raids Again ". And the question encompasses EVERY monster in the Godzilla cannon.

Comment: @KingsAdviser A vegetarian diet doesn't seem likely for Pandas either.

Comment: Panda K9s are an unnecessary evolutionary side effect of being an Ursa, and every other function in their digestive system is specifically designed to process bamboo. You defeated your own argument. ( I'm gonna be a zoology major)

Comment: They also have a body fat index similar to polar bears, who are considerably larger, and not enough muscle tone to go faster than a light trot. They are living plush toys (who are stronger than humans). I mean you defeated your own argument as in they can't logically be mistaken for predators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've gone through plot summaries of every Godzilla movie to date, and there's only one example of a scene where one Kaiju consumes, or attempts to eat, another. In [**Rodan**](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Rodan_(1956_film)) (1956), the newly-hatched Rodan feeds on the Meganulon surrounding the egg. Beyond that, I haven't been able to find any cases of one monster feeding on another. This leads me to believe that, **so far, there have been no other instances of one Kaiju actually eating another**.

As per your examples, the Kamoeba corpse in Tokyo S.O.S. indicated CLAW marks, not bite marks. This led them to believe that the creature was killed in battle with Godzilla (or a similar monster). Orga, on the other hand, was not attempting to eat Godzilla, but rather to absorb his DNA.

Now, that said, it's important to note that Kaiju MAY have eaten other Kaiju "in the wild", where such things were not shown on-screen. The few glimpses we received of life on Monster Island showed the monsters fighting, but it's safe to assume that life in such a place would be similar to that in the time of the dinosaurs, with a defined food chain & pecking order. On the other hand, many of the monsters found on Monster Island are unique specimens rather than  examples of an entire species.

If you're interested in learning more about Kaiju in the Godzilla canon, I highly recommend visiting the [**Godzilla Wiki**](http://godzilla.wikia.com) site. It has detailed profiles about pretty much every Kaiju featured in the Godzilla universe, including dietary requirements & natural behavior (when such information is available for the monster type). There are also a range of comics & novels featuring Godzilla, most of which I'm not familiar with. It's entirely possibly that another example exists there.

***Credit:*** Thanks to @WillFeldman for pointing out the Rodan reference.

Comment: What about in the graphic novels?

Answer (score 4):

We do see a newly hatched Rodan eating several Meganulons in the original [Rodan](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Meganulon), (1956).

> Shigeru able to regain conscious after he survived the cave-in and
>   only realize that he is now trapped inside the Meganulon's lair,
>   surrounded by hundreds of Meganulons, where he discovered that the
>   Meganulon weren't the only creatures that are awakened by the atomic
>   weapon test, but also a giant egg that was sitting right in the middle
>   of the cave as the egg sudden began to stir and hatches into the
>   gigantic ancient winged monster known as Rodan. Rodan proceeds to eat
>   the entire group of Meganulons in the cave until it has enough
>   strength to break through the ground and fly away.

Comment: I completely forgot about those bear sized worms

Comment: +1, I scanned the summary for Rodan and completely missed that part. Now I have to change my answer, since it's flat-out wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more example where a Kaiju or KAiju like being feeds on another Kaiju (not directly eating, but feeding on its energy). The Guirus and Megaguirus in the film Godzilla vs. Megaguirus (2000), tried to sap Godzillas Energy.

Thus not a real eating in the sense, but more a sapping of Godzillas energy.

Edit:
If we take also american films into account, there is a parasitic Kaiju race, the Mutos which seem to be able to use Godzillas species as a breeding ground (the young ones (not sure if larvae, egss,...) still though don't eat the flesh but the energy within the kaiju and killing it that way).